# Can i fix Cumulative Layout Shift without knowing the width and hight of an Image?

Tags: html, sass, lighthouse, cumulative-layout-shift

I tried aspect-ratio and the padding-top trick, but is there a way to automate all of this?

Comment: So you do know the aspect-ratio? If yes, what happend when you did this that can't be automated?

Comment: Okay, let me ask it like this: Is there a way to fix CLS without explicit width, hight or aspect-ratio?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you don't control the documents (to set explicit heights/widths), the resources (to speed things up with progressive jpgs) or the server (to use http2 push or add explicit http headers) and you want to do this stricly with css.

Unless I'm missing something, it can't be done with precision.

What you could do is to *reduce the amplitude* of the CLS by setting a `min-height` on the image wrapper element, at the minimum of possible outcomes. This way, the CLS will be for the difference only, not for the whole height.

It can be done either:

A - easy - If you know that no picture will be less than *so many* pixels high*, not ser, you'd set a min-height on the wrapper equal to that number of pixels.

*(pixels in actual display, not those of the original file, the figures may match or not depening on your implementation)

B - mildly-complex - If you know that no picture will have an aspect ratio less than sometheing, you'd set a min-height in `vw`, where the exact value is the result of a specific calculation** for each media query.

**(for example, a 2/1 or bigger image - such as 1000x500px - will sit safely in a `min-height="50vw"` wrapper if it's on a full-width column or in a `min-height="25vw"` wrapper if on a half-width column and so on)